# Not able to post Data on Server

Tags: android, post, android-asynctask

I am posting value on server and getting response.But problem is that its showing me null as response.What is the mistake i am doing.I have tried many methods of post but still have not found any solution.Can anyone help me.
Following is my code-

```
class SendPostReqAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        String OTPTxt = otp.getText().toString();

        int CustID = 2;

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

            HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("mylink?CustID=" + CustID + "&OTP=" + OTPTxt);
            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairList = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            try {
                UrlEncodedFormEntity urlEncodedFormEntity = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairList);
                httpPost.setEntity(urlEncodedFormEntity);
                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                InputStream inputStream = httpResponse.getEntity().getContent();

                InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);

                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);

                StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

                String bufferedStrChunk = null;

                while ((bufferedStrChunk = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                    stringBuilder.append(bufferedStrChunk);
                }

                return stringBuilder.toString();

            } catch (ClientProtocolException cpe) {
                System.out.println("Firstption caz of HttpResponese :" + cpe);
                cpe.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException ioe) {
                System.out.println("Secondption caz of HttpResponse :" + ioe);
                ioe.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }


       @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            super.onPostExecute(s);
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Toast.makeText(OTPScreen1.this, "Posting Data to server", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Toast.makeText(OTPScreen1.this, "posting data " + responseServer, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

Have called this method on buttonclick

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                 new SendPostReqAsyncTask().execute();
}
});
```

Comment: `Toast.makeText(OTPScreen1.this, "posting data " + responseServer, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }`. responseServer is not used. You should use String s instead. And remove the runOnUiTread(). Its not needed in onPostExecute.

Comment: @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            super.onPostExecute(s);
            Toast.makeText(OTPScreen1.this, "Posting Data to server", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Toast.makeText(OTPScreen1.this, "posting data " + s, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    Should i write like this?

Comment: Still its showing me null as response

Comment: have you declared internet permission in your manifest file?

Comment: Yes have declared it already

Comment: If s==null then doInBackground returned null. So you had an exception! You can return e.getMessage() in catch blocks.

Comment: have you added something to your namevalue parameter list? You have just created list of namevalue parameters